# How to parse a JSON friend list to hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json, koala

I have in some file contains this json part (from FACEBOOK API):

```
--- !seq:Koala::Facebook::API::GraphCollection - name: pop ool id: "1032225" - name: Rose kak id: "2312010"
```

and in ruby I try to do:

```
jsonFriends = File.open("friends.json" ,"r")

puts JSON.parse(jsonFriends.readline)
```

but I get this error:

```
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse' from try.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON to me at all.

Comment: Indeed, that looks a lot like YAML to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [YAML](http://YAML.Org/), not [JSON](http://JSON.Org/).

```
require 'yaml'

friends = YAML.load(File.read('friends.json'))
```

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): block sequence entries are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 48 (Psych::SyntaxError)
 from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
 from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
 from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
 from try.rb:24:in `<main>'

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
require 'json'
result = File.read("friends.json")
puts JSON.parse(result)
```

Comment: `result = File.read("issues.json")
p result # "{\"status\":801,\"errors\":[\"Failed login for '\"]}\n"`
---------------
`r = File.open("issues.json",'r')
p r ##<File:issues.json>`

Open just open that file but not read it.